# Create searchable pdf from html and css using angular - not work with jspdf

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I tried to use jspdf.js and html2canvas.js libs to save my HTML page with CSS design (using angular) to searchable pdf file.

First try - not save my CSS design.

```
let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4');

    let handleElement = {
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){
        return true;
      }
    };
    doc.fromHTML(DATA.innerHTML,15,15,{
      'width': 200,
      'elementHandlers': handleElement
    });

    doc.save('angular-demo.pdf');
```

Second try - not save as searchable pdf.

```
      var data = document.getElementById('htmlData');
      html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        var imgWidth = 208;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        var position = 0;
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
        pdf.save('newPDF.pdf');
      });
```

Hope someone can help me - how can I save my HTML page with CSS design to searchable pdf file.

Comment: still not fixed

Comment: Did you find the solution?